# How to effectively Unit Test a DAL that uses ADO.NET and SQL Server with NUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mocking, nunit, data-access-layer

So you have a DAL in C# that using the Repository pattern and you have an interface for each Repository. It is backed by ADO.NET, MS SQL Server, and Stored Procedure calls.

This is great for stubbing/mocking out the repository where it is being used else where when doing unit tests, and I Love it!

However, I would love to add some unit testing for the DAL itself. Preferably using Rhino Mocks with NUnit. However I am open to switching to MoQ if a solid case could be made that it can do something that Rhino can't in relation to this question.

I would rather not have it talk to any DB during the Unit Tests to keep they more "pure" while still effectively testing the DAL itself. If however you can not really effectively unit test a DAL itself without it talking to a DB, what would be the alternatives that could be in memory replacements or a portable file based replacements that are compatible with of SQL Server and same SqlConnection and SqlCommand calls.

Open to refactoring the DAL if needed to make it easier to inject as long as it doesn't over complicate the design at the same time. Already using Microsoft Unity, for DI with the Repository Pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What exactly would those *unit tests* test? Considering typical DAL code is rarely anything more than delegating actual work to 3rd party data access code (ADO.NET, EntityFramework, NHibernate).

I haven't used ADO.NET much, but I suppose this NHibernate example is sufficient enough:

```
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Get<User>(id);
    }
}
```

Of course, assuming the code is wrote correctly, all the dependencies (`sessionFactory` namely) would be passed via interfaces and therefore easy to stub, so writing unit test **is possible** (you'll just have to mock a lot of stuff to make it happen).

Purist approach would be to write such unit test, as it's yet another data point proving your code indeed does what you assume (calling `Get`). However, note that test like this is rather expensive, as you essentially have to stub entire database access made by your provider (mocking `sessionFactory` to return mocked session which is then checked for calls made).

This is difficult decision to be made (whether follow purist approach in this case), as you will have to write [integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) with real database anyways. And those tests will cover **exactly the same** areas as unit tests you'd wrote, but working in real environment (instead of stubbed one).

In my experience, unit testing DAL is usually not worth the benefits it offers, especially when contrasted with its rather high costs (time spent writing code to stub the database environment) for unit test) and existence of proper integration tests suite.

And last, I would advise against using in-memory database in any kind of testing. For the reasons below:

- it is slow
- it has several possible failure points that may be difficult to control (ORM configuration, in-memory database setup, possibly invalid test data)
- gives you false sense of doing integration testing (while you're not; in-memory database might behave entirely different than your real, production one)

Unless you can load up exactly the same database to the memory, stick to proper integration tests (that would be DAL testing priority) with isolated unit tests backup (only if you can afford to write them).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, it is just ADO.NET, SQL Server and Stored Proc's, there is no ORM at all.  The unit tests would be testing that your SQL is valid and that you are converting the results from SQL to a POCO that the repository interface returns.  You want to make sure the DAL has valid SQL statements and passes params correctly, and that the converting of data types is working as expected.

Comment: @RodneyFoley: yep, the cost of writing such test is still high (stubbing *any* kind of ORM or ADO code is hard). And you essentially accomplish what you'd do with integration test. Note that those test will be extremely fragile, as the slightest change in SQL (say formatting), even tho will yield no change in application workings will break unit test. I'm not saying "don't do that"; I'm warning that those tests will be expensive and there's already cheap alternative in integration tests (which you should have anyways).

Comment: I agree with your statements in your answer. What I think I will do is write unit tests against the type conversions that they convert correctly, then push the remainder to our integration tests and be done with.  At worse for quick developer sanity checks I may write a few unit tests that is really an Integration Test with the ignore flag so we can ran as needed when making changes to SQL statements before checking in.  Thanks Jimmy!